# C error, double expects double*

Tags: c

Just started using C and I'm getting 1 error on my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //declare variables
    double speed = 1.4, hours, totalYards;

    //prompt user to enter amount of hours
    printf("Enter the amount of hours: ");
    scanf("%lf", &hours);

    //calculate amount of yards taken
    totalYards = speed * hours;

    //display result to user
    printf("The total amount of yards is %.2f", &totalYards);

    return 0;
}
```

and the error is

warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *' [-Wformat]|

on the last printf.

Comment: `&totalYards` isn't a double. - it's the ADDRESS OF (e.g. a pointer) to a double.

Comment: I feel like this is almost certainly a duplicate but I don't know of a canonical answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 printf("The total amount of yards is %.2f", &totalYards);
```

to

```
  printf("The total amount of yards is %.2f", totalYards);
```

You were passing a pointer object (type `double *`) but `f` requires you to pass a value of type `double`.

Comment: Add'l: It's important to understand that `scanf` and `printf` are different here.  `printf` does not take pointers, because it only needs the *values* to print.  `scanf` does take pointers, because that's how it gains write access to *variables* in the caller's stack frame.  (This *appears* not to be the case for arrays of `char` (often referred to as strings) which of course confuses the issue.)  (Of course one should never use `scanf` for anything in production-quality software, but grokking this difference and why it has to be present is valuable in gaining competence in the language.)

Comment: @user3561624 ,  "Thank you" comments are frowned upon . Instead you could've accepted the answer.